# Can you write a static assert to verify the offset of data members?

Tags: c++, assert

Given the following struct:

```
struct ExampleStruct {
    char firstMember[8];
    uint64_t secondMember;
};
```

Is there a way to write a static assert to verify that the offset of `secondMember` is some multiple of 8 bytes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your type has standard layout, you can use the `offsetof` macro:

```
#include <cstddef>

static_assert(offsetof(ExampleStruct, secondMember) % 8 == 0, "Bad alignment");
```

This the `offsetof` macro results in a constant expression, you can use a static assertion to produce a translation error if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 11):

### `Offsetof`

You can use the `offsetof` marco brought by the `cstddef` library. Here I first get the offset, then I use the [modulus operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) to check if it is a multiple of 8. Then, if the remainder is 0, the offset is indeed a multiple of 8 bytes.

```
// Offset.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdarg.h>

struct ExampleStruct {
    char firstMember[8];
    uint64_t secondMember;
};


int main()
{
     size_t offset = offsetof(ExampleStruct, secondMember);
     if(offset%8==0)
        std::cout << "Offset is a multiple of 8 bytes";
}
```

Demo [**here**](http://cpp.sh/73yo2)

### `Offsetof` with `static_assert`

Or by the context of this question, the goal is to have a `static_assert`. Well, that is pretty much the same thing:

```
// OffsetAssert.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdarg.h>

struct ExampleStruct {
    char firstMember[8];
    uint64_t secondMember;
};


int main()
{
     size_t offset = offsetof(ExampleStruct, secondMember); // Get Offset
     static_assert(offsetof(ExampleStruct, secondMember)%8==0,"Not Aligned 8 Bytes"); // Check if the offset modulus 8 is remainer 0 , if so it is a multiple of 8
     std::cout << "Aligned 8 Bytes" << std::endl; // If Assert Passes it is aligned 8 bytes
}
```

Demo [**here**](http://cpp.sh/8elc)

### Type Uses

I use `std::size_t` type because that's the type you normally use to store sizes of variables, objects, and so on. And also because it expands to the `std::size_t` expression according to cppreference.com:

> The macro `offsetof` expands to an integral constant expression of type `std::size_t`, the value of which is the offset, in bytes, from the beginning of an object of specified type to its specified member, including padding if any.

### References

[cpprefrence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)

[cplusplus](https://www.google.com/search?q=offsetof+c%2B%2B&oq=offsetof+c%2B%2B&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2654j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)